# Faces acting wierdly without me having anything done with them

Tags: modeling, faces

I was following the Doughnut tutorial from blender guru (the latest) and was making the saucer for the coffee cup and due to me messing up one of the earlier insets and had to get creative when making the insets for the slot of the coffee cup. so instead if having the round singular face to inset i had several rectangular faces which all need 1 inset line, so what i did was a selected them all and trial and error the insetting until I got the thin faces i needed. Then when I was about to raise the middle section to actually create the cup slot i noticed that one face was glitched out of its mind so I took to the internet and found no good answer, let see if anyone else had similar problems. notes i have a solidify modifier already applied.[image: here is the glitch]. Here is a google drive link to the project where you can download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F22EEk7GTJZkgE1uVcp_nyMTs8PkKFsj/view?usp=sharing.

ps: this is my first time doing anything here so if I make mistakes, please tell me in a nice way.

Comment: Hello, I think the right way to handle this is to scrap everything and start from scratch. You'll learn way more that way. After all you are following a beginner course, you should try to achieve it gracefully if you can, and try again if you fail, that way you won't make the same mistake again later on. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I hoped their might have been a quick fix but I had a suspicion that there would not be. Once again thanks.